# Why is it that my mysql content in xampp cannot be displayed using php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database in xampp, made a very simple php script that access/connect to mysql in xampp(saved it to xampp/htdocs). The connection is ok, but when I ran it to a browser, only a table I created in php appeared but the data in mysql did not. What could be the problem?

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['name'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['age'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Is there any data in the example table?

Comment: Start to learn how to debug PHP scripts. What is your error reporting configuration? What does the HTML source in the browser say (not the standard view, but view source)?

Answer (score 2):

If you just started to use PHP and MySQL why not starting to learn PDO as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Make sure you have data in the `example` table, check with PHPMyAdmin and follow [this nice guide](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Your code should be:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM example");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['age'];
        echo "</td></tr>"; 
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: new to php finds difficult, can use `mysqli` instead